# clustering using a proximity matrix in r

Tags: r, cluster-computing, mahalanobis

I have a proximity matrix (dissimilarity) of an mahalanobis distance.

the matrix (sample):

```
> dput(MD[1:5,1:5])

structure(c(0, 10.277, 8.552, 8.592, 9.059, 10.277, 0, 10.917, 
9.489, 8.176, 8.552, 10.917, 0, 8.491, 8.104, 8.592, 9.489, 8.491, 
0, 9.375, 9.059, 8.176, 8.104, 9.375, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("2", "4", "5", "6", "9"), c("X2", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X9"
    )))
```

the matrix has 1900 people and the row name are an Id. 
I need to cluster those people and the to get a number of a cluster next to the person's id.

I know how to cluster using k-means but I don't how to cluster when you have already a dissimilarity matrix.

Comment: what did you mean by "a number of a cluster"?

Comment: @d.b isn't pca for feature selection? what would it do for clustering?

Comment: @thisisrg I mean id 5 cluster nu. 4 id 345 cluster nu. 1, but as a table.

Comment: @d.b tnx, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hierarchical clustering, starting with the Mahalanobis distance matrix:

```
MD
      X2     X4     X5    X6    X9
#2  0.000 10.277  8.552 8.592 9.059
#4 10.277  0.000 10.917 9.489 8.176
#5  8.552 10.917  0.000 8.491 8.104
#6  8.592  9.489  8.491 0.000 9.375
#9  9.059  8.176  8.104 9.375 0.000

hc <- hclust(as.dist(MD))

clusters <- cutree(hc, k = 3) # obtain 3 clusters
clusters
#2 4 5 6 9 
#1 2 3 1 3 

plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, k = 3, border = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: tnx, I will try it. Question - what the height stands for? I mean for what is the scale?

Comment: do you have to specify as.dist in hclust? I thought it already takes in a dissimilarity matrix.

Comment: it's already is a dissimilarity matrix, but it doesn't work otherwise. is it tempering with the data?

Comment: I don't see how just passing MD will not work. I have made an attempt below.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I get: Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @Hila De  height is proportional to the distance.

Comment: @Sandipan Dey if im using as.dist(MD) it is changing the data? because it already a distance..

Comment: Don't use `dist` , use `as.dist`

Comment: you dont have to recompute the distance matrix, instead just convert the `matrix` object you already have to a `dist` object with `as.dist`

Comment: @Sandipan Dey if more then half of the people are in one group does it mean that the code isn't good or the distance isn't right?

Comment: @Hila De it depends, you can try to zoom that part of the dendogram too see whether the intra-cluster distances are really small or not. Alternatively, you can try to compute the cluster quality by using metrics such as SSE which should be small. You can also use higher number of clusters to see if the larger cluster gets splitted into smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, using `dendextend`:

```
fit<-hclust(MD)

fit %>% as.dendrogram %>% 
  set("branches_k_color", k = 3, value = c("purple", "orange","red")) %>% 
  plot
```

The cluster # are specified by colors ... passed on from `cutree`.